# How do I create a stable download link for electron-builder releases?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I'm using electron-builder to package an app for Windows/MacOS & trying to configure auto-update with the [electron-publisher-s3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-publisher-s3) package.

The default naming for the published Windows artifact is `${productName}_Setup_${version}.${ext}`, or `foo_Setup_1.0.0.exe`

This means that the download link, `dl.example.com/win/foo_Setup_1.0.0.exe` will change each update.

My first guess is to just remove dynamic variables from the artifact naming pattern, but I'm assuming the version # is there for a reason & don't want to break anything.

Is there a way to manage a stable download link, like `dl.example.com/win/latest`, `dl.example.com/win/beta`, etc. ?

Comment: There is a section about [provider](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/wiki/Auto-Update#module_electron-updater.Provider+getLatestVersion) which might solve your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there are no ready solutions. You can use [Amazon S3 Routing Rules](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-websiteconfiguration-routingrules-redirectrule.html) to redirect `win/latest` to `win/foo_Setup_1.0.0.exe` (and you need to change this rule after each release).

I suggest you to [file issue](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/new) to electron-builder and someday it will be implemented for you. i.e. electron-builder will automatically create and maintain such rules for you.

Comment: Thanks @develar. In the meantime, is there a problem with naming the artifact without the version number, eg `foo_setup.exe`?

Comment: @Brandon In general, it it safe to remove version number from file name. But in this case user will be not able to download old version if need.